# Ajuda com a biblioteca argparse

Tags: python-3.x, linha-de-comando, argumento

Estou tentando utilizar a biblioteca `argparse` para guiar o modulo principal (`__main__`) entre duas possíveis execuções:

```
import unittest
import argparse


arg = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='Execution type')
arg.add_argument('--type', action='store', dest='argument', type=int, default=0,
                 required=False, help='Chose the execution type (0=application, 1=unittest)')

options = arg.parse_args()


def main():
    pass


def run_tests():

    from tests import tests_models, tests_dbconnections, tests_dals

    suit = unittest.TestSuite()
    suit.addTest(unittest.makeSuite(tests_models.TestPerson))
    suit.addTest(unittest.makeSuite(tests_models.TestClient))
    suit.addTest(unittest.makeSuite(tests_dbconnections.TestPgSqlConnection))
    suit.addTest(unittest.makeSuite(tests_dals.TestPgSqlDal))

    return suit

if __name__ == '__main__':
    if options.argument:
        unittest.main(defaultTest='run_tests', verbosity=2)
    else:
        main()
```

Mas ao executar: `python3 start.py --type 1`

Recebo um erro informando que o argumento `--type` não é reconhecido:
`usage: start.py [-h] [-v] [-q] [--locals] [-f] [-c] [-b] [tests [tests ...]]
start.py: error: unrecognized arguments: --type`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Isso acontece quando o `unittest` assume o controle, ele vai interpretar as opções de linha de comando novamente. `--type` é um argumento válido para a aplicação principal, não para o `unittest`.

Você tem que separar as opções de linha de comando do `unittest` e da aplicação principal. Uma forma de fazer isso é usar [`argparse.parse_known_args()`](https://docs.python.org/dev/library/argparse.html#argparse.ArgumentParser.parse_known_args) ao invés de [`argparse.parse_args()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html#argparse.ArgumentParser.parse_args), veja:

> (Documentação)
>
> Às vezes, um *script* só pode analisar alguns dos argumentos de linha de comando, passando os argumentos restantes para outro *script* ou programa.
>
> Nestes casos, o método `parse_known_args()` pode ser útil. Ele funciona
>   como `parse_args()` exceto que ele não produz um erro quando argumentos
>   extras estão presentes. Em vez disso, ele retorna uma tupla de dois
>   itens que contém o *namespace* populado e a lista dos argumentos restantes.

Código:

```
import argparse, unittest, sys

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description = 'Execution type')
parser.add_argument('--test', action = 'store_true',
                              help = 'Executar o unittest')

options, args = parser.parse_known_args()

def main():
    pass

def run_tests():
    from tests import tests_models, tests_dbconnections, tests_dals

    suit = unittest.TestSuite()
    suit.addTest(unittest.makeSuite(tests_models.TestPerson))
    suit.addTest(unittest.makeSuite(tests_models.TestClient))
    suit.addTest(unittest.makeSuite(tests_dbconnections.TestPgSqlConnection))
    suit.addTest(unittest.makeSuite(tests_dals.TestPgSqlDal))

    return suit

if __name__ == '__main__':
    if options.test:
        sys.argv[1:] = args
        unittest.main(defaultTest = 'run_tests', verbosity = 2)
    else:
        main()
```

Para chamar o `unittest` faça:

```
python3 nomedoScript.py --test
```

Para executar a aplicação principal chame o *script* sem argumentos:

```
python3 nomedoScript.py
```

Comment: Testei com as modificações que você fez. O erro realmente não acontece mais, porém a função de tests nunca é chamada. O caminho seguido sempre é a função `main`, mesmo que não passemos nada como parâmetro: `python3 start.py`.
Outra coisa que não me agradou, foi o uso de `sys.argv`. `sys.argv` já é por si só uma forma (arcaica?) de receber parâmetros de linha de comando. Dispensando assim o uso de `argparse`.
Acho que o erro não está relacionado ao unittest. Comente a linha `unittest.main(main(defaultTest = 'run_tests', verbosity = 2))` e verás que o erro ainda persiste.

Comment: Correto! o Erro foi meu, eu estava passando o parâmetro errado na hora de executar (passando `--test` em vez de `--type`). Ao chamar `python3 start.py --type 1` a função `main` é chamada.

1º Mas ao chamar sem passar nada `python3 start.py --type` ele reclama a falta do parâmetro:

`usage: start.py [-h] [--type ARGUMENT]
start.py: error: argument --type: expected one argument`

Parece que o `default=0` não está cumprindo o seu papel.

2º Não existe uma maneira de resolver o problema do unittest sem usar `sys.argv`? Não gosto dele pelos motivos que já citei.

Comment: Não funciona, ele continua reclamando a falta do valor.

Comment: @MatheusSaraiva Aqui pra mim funciona, veja se o teu código é parecido com esse aqui: http://pastebin.com/Cd4XkUnp

Comment: Exatamente igual, foi copy and paste puro.

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/43197/discussion-between-matheus-saraiva-and-zekk).

Comment: ok, sou eu novamente executando de forma errada.
Para usar o parâmetro default não precisa passar nada: `python3 start.py`. O argumento --type só é necessário caso queira passar algum valor.

Comment: Analizando agora o resultado final, esse não é o formato mais adequado para esse meu caso. O ideal seria que, se for executado de forma limpa `python3 start.py` a aplicação seja executada, e se for passado o argumento --test (apenas o argumento sem valor nenhum) `python3 start.py --test` os tests serão executados.

Comment: @MatheusSaraiva Atualizei a resposta, veja se é isso.